# Client side text search using CSS3 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Thanks to this idea
http://www.redotheweb.com/2013/05/15/client-side-full-text-search-in-css.html, I implemented a client side text search using CSS3 data attributes and JQuery.

This is an HTML example

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<a id="btn">Filter</a>

<ul>
    <li data-index="A01658">A01658 and other stuff</li>
    <li data-index="A09956">A09956 and other stuff</li>
    <li data-index="B25628">B25628 and other stuff</li>
    <li data-index="A01777">A01777 and other stuff</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the JS code (jQuery required)

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('ul > li:not([data-index=\"' + $('#search').val() + '\"])').hide();
});
```

It works. But only "full" text. I need to let the users to perform "partial" text search (a good example is LIKE operator in MySQL).
If "A01" is entered, both first and fourth box should remain visible.
If "995" is entered, only second box should remain visible.

In there any chance to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Here is http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```
 $('#btn').click(function() {
   $('ul > li:not([data-index*=\"' + $('#search').val() + '\"])').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one here. This would work as and when the user types in the search field and filter LI's accordingly. This is also case insensitive.

```
var items = $('ul > li');
var search = $('#search');

search.on("keyup", function() {
    items.show().filter(function() {
        return $(this).data("index").toLowerCase().indexOf(search.val().toLowerCase()) < 0
    }).hide();
});
```

Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj2ercp1/)